# Updating the results of a select

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

I have a table caxnode which has fields node_alias, node_mode, node_id, etc..

In some cases, the node_alias is marked as "regular" as well as 'logical' for different node_id's. I want to change the entries for which the same node_alias is marked 'regular' as well as 'logical' to logical. i.e. change the "regular" to "logical" if the same entry is marked 'logical' in the table and is an LDOM partition ..

This is my working query to return the results that I am interested in changing..

```
select Node_ID, Node_type, Num_of_proc, Node_Alias, Host_ID, Node_mode, Partition_Type
from CAXNODE nd
where (Node_mode = 'VIRTUAL' or Node_mode = 'REGULAR')
and Node_Alias in
    (select nd2.Node_Alias
     from CAXNODE nd2
     where nd2.Node_mode = 'LOGICAL' and Partition_Type = 'LDOM'
    ) ;
```

Now I want to change the values to set Node_mode to 'LOGICAL'; Partition_Type to 'LDOM', Host_ID to (nd2.Host_ID); Num_of_proc to (nd2.Num_of_proc);

How can I do this in one update statement?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Remove the SELECT, and replace with UPDATE [target], then add the SET list of changes.

```
--select Node_ID, Node_type, Num_of_proc, Node_Alias, Host_ID, Node_mode, Partition_Type
UPDATE nd
SET
    Node_mode = 'LOGICAL',
    Partition_Type = 'LDOM',
    Host_ID = nd2.Host_ID,
    Num_of_proc = nd2 Num_of_proc
from CAXNODE nd
where (Node_mode = 'VIRTUAL' or Node_mode = 'REGULAR')
and Node_Alias in
    (select nd2.Node_Alias
     from CAXNODE nd2
     where nd2.Node_mode = 'LOGICAL' and Partition_Type = 'LDOM'
    ) ;
```

Comment: Am getting a syntax error from access for this one.. I tried simply UPDATE CAXNODE 
SET
    Node_mode = 'LOGICAL',
    Partition_Type = 'LDOM',
    Host_ID = nd2.Host_ID
from caxnode nd1
where (Node_mode = 'VIRTUAL' or Node_mode = 'REGULAR')
and Node_Alias in
    (select nd2.Node_Alias
     from CAXNODE nd2
     where nd2.Node_mode = 'LOGICAL' and Partition_Type = 'LDOM'
    ) ; but it says syntax error(missing expression) in query expression 'nd2.host_id' from caxnode nd1'

Comment: dont think update from is supported by ansi sql. could you please help me out with ansi sql that will work on oracle as well ?

Comment: @cyberkiwi  tried

UPDATE caxnode AS nd SET nd.Node_mode = 'LOGICAL', nd.Partition_Type = 'LDOM', nd.Host_ID = nd2.Host_ID, nd.Num_of_proc = nd2.Num_of_proc WHERE (nd.Node_mode = 'VIRTUAL' or nd.Node_mode = 'REGULAR') and Node_Alias in (select Node_Alias from CAXNODE nd2 where nd2.Node_mode = 'LOGICAL' and nd2.Partition_Type = 'LDOM' );

and when i double click the query in access, i see the correct rows that need to change, but when i run the query, it asks me for value of nd2.host_id ! :(

Comment: There is no ANSI sql for UPDATE-FROM-JOIN. Each DBMS vendor does this differently. Is Oracle all you need?